# AndroidViewClient: view not found error

Tags: androidviewclient

I am trying to search a video in youtube using AndroidViewClient.

```
package = 'com.google.android.youtube'
activity = 'com.google.android.apps.youtube.app.WatchWhileActivity'

component = package + "/" + activity

device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()
device.startActivity(component=component)

vc = ViewClient(device, serialno)

search = vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise(
    re.compile(u'''Search'''))
search.touch()

search = vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(re.compile(u'Search\ YouTube'))
search.type('hello')
device.press('KEYCODE_ENTER')
```

The line :

```
search = vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(re.compile(u'Search\ YouTube'))
```

Throws a view not found error even though there is a view with the exact text.

It works if i dump the window:

```
vc.dump(window='-1')
search = vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(re.compile(u'Search\ YouTube'))
```

Can anyone tell me why this is necessary? How do i recognize that i have to dump the window before finding a view, any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you do something that changes the screen like

```
search.touch()
```

you should invoke

```
vc.dump(window='-1')
```

to refresh the internal representation of the screen and being able to search or interact with the new Views that were not there before.

Also, you can use `culebra -G` to start [Culebra GUI](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI) and point and click on the UI representation to generate the script, which will generate the `dump()` when needed.